# Specific date after number of dates

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Currently I'm working on `NSDate` and `NSDateFormatter`.

My issue is I need to `find the date after 100 days` of the user specified date.

Currently I'm using this hard-coded string for finding a future date.

```
calendar.maximumDate = [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:@"20/08/2015"];
```

But it is not correct way and not work with user specified date. Is there anyway to achieve this ?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
// How much day to add
int addDaysCount = 100;

// Create and initialize date component instance
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setDay:addDaysCount];

// Retrieve date with increased days count
NSDate *newDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] 
                          dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents 
                                          toDate:fromdateHere options:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

- [(id)dateWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds sinceDate:(NSDate *)date](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithTimeInterval%3asinceDate%3a) does all you need.

Here's an example:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate new];
NSTimeInterval hundredDaysTimeInterval = 3600*24*100;
NSDate *nowAndAHundred = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:hundredDaysTimeInterval sinceDate:now];
```

Comment: This is the WRONG way to achieve this. Adding seconds does not take into account daylight savings changes, and can result in the wrong answer

Comment: Damn you're right! I've never thought about this. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. @AshleyMills so what is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Use `dateByAddingTimeInterval` function in `NSDate`. Like

```
int daysToAdd = 100;
NSDate *maximumDate = [yourDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];
```

Comment: See my comment on @Pierre's answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

use nsdate instance method "- (id)dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds" and pass (100 * 86400) as argument to get the date after 100 days from the user specified date. Call this method using user specified date which is instance of nsdate.

Comment: See my comment on @Pierre's answer